# How to Create folder based on User ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

I am writing 1 webmethod for receiving PDF file  sent by  other website user....here is the code

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Sub GetFile(ByVal fileBytes As Byte(), ByVal fileName As String, ByVal USER_ID   As Integer)
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), fileName), fileBytes)
End Sub
```

End Class

Above code will write file to application root folder with given file name...

but  in root folder i want to  create the folder  by the name of that userid and store the pdf file in that folder.

So how to acheive this one??

```
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/USER_ID/"))
    File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/USER_ID/"), fileBytes)
```

vaidate code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create folder structure based on user id, department etc.. try like below

```
Dim dinfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/{0}/{1}/", USER_ID, department)))

If Not dinfo.Exists Then
    dinfo.Create()
End If

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.Combine(dinfo.FullName, fileName), fileBytes)
```

Comment: damith..i want that users will ve different userid so different folder should be created  and then their respective pdf file should be saved in that folder,based on userid..i hope u unserstood what i want to do..like 21....has 1.pdf ,,,,,23 has s.pdf//like thhis..if i want to add some more folder like department name then????

Comment: i have mentioned some doubt in above comment..so Damith...reply

Comment: Damith, seyed .i am getting error:department is a type cant be used as a expression

Comment: @loveforasp.net as same as you send `USER_ID` parameter, you need to send 'department' as well

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that folder is exist before adding file to it:

VB.net:

```
Imports System.IO


Dim path__1 As String = String.Format("~/{0}/", USER_ID)
Dim folder As String= Server.MapPath(path__1)
If Not Directory.Exists(folder) Then
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder)
End If
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(path__1), fileName), fileBytes)
```

C#:

```
using System.IO;


string path = String.Format("~/{0}/", USER_ID);

string folder = Server.MapPath(path);
if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(path), fileName), fileBytes);
```

Comment: sayed, what would be complete code by combining your code aswell as Damith code ?

Comment: Technically codes are equal. But my code is secure because it first check is there any folder by name `User ID`. If is do not create that folder, otherwise create it.

Comment: i just used damith code..i am getting error:suggest me your code see damith.have mentioned departmnet as well userid...os i request u to provide your code containing both

Comment: You does not mentioned what is `department`. Please add it to your question and i will help you.

Comment: i try your code also seyed..getting error that VAR is not defined